# Hibernate does not create FK relations and references automatically (using Spring Boot)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, database-design, foreign-keys, schema

I have a problem with my Spring Boot app (using hibernate). I have the following 3 entities. When I run my app, my DB Schema will be automatically created (just what I want), BUT for the FK and relations part. Where i should have a FK, I just have a INT column witch does not reference anything...

Please find below the 3 entities and down on the bottom the generated schema...

PS: I am using MySQL.

Ingredient

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ingredients")
public class Ingredient {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="name", length=50)
private String name;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="recipe_ingredient",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="recipe_id"))
private List<Recipe> recipes;

++ getters and setters
```

Recipe

```
@Entity
@Table(name="recipes")
public class Recipe {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="title", length=100)
private String title;

@Column(name="description", length=3000)
private String description;

@Column(name="short_presentation", length=200)
private String shortPresentation;

@Column(name="image_url", length=200)
private String imageUrl;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name="recipe_ingredient",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="recipe_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id"))
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

@Column(name="minutes")
private int cookingTimeInMinutes;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="difficulty_id")
private Difficulty difficulty;

+ getters and setters
```

Difficulty

```
@Entity
@Table(name="difficulties")
public class Difficulty {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="difficulty", length=50)
    private String difficulty;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="difficulty",
            cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private List<Recipe> recipes;

+ getters and setters
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

[DB generate Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZc1y.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: please give some more details and make clear your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your configuration is default to MyISAM Storage Engine which does not support FK as per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).

Please configure your hibernate dialect to InnoDB:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```